# set focus inside a user control with VB6

Tags: vb6, user-controls, setfocus

I'm working with VB6. 
I have several forms and i need open a form. This form have a UserControl. 
My problem is setfocus in a element of UserControl inside this form.

```
Sub Form_Activate()
    Ctrl_User.MyTextbox.SetFocus
End Sub
```

but don't run

How i can do it??

Thanks

Comment: what if you set `TabIndex` to 0 to the usercontrol directly in the properties window? When you open the form it will just automatically focus the control with TabIndex 0 inside your UC.

Comment: I have the usercontrol with tabindex=0. but don't run

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
Sub Form_Activate()
    Ctrl_User.Enabled = True
    Ctrl_User.MyTextbox.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Also maybe you may need to review this here as well it may help you more:

> If you're authoring a user-drawn control, there won't be any
>   constituent controls on your UserControl. If you don't want your
>   control to be able to receive the focus, set the CanGetFocus property
>   of the UserControl object to False. CanGetFocus is True by default.
>
> If your user-drawn control can receive the focus, the UserControl
>   object will receive GotFocus and LostFocus events when your control
>   receives and loses the focus. A user-drawn control is responsible for
>   drawing its own focus rectangle when it has the focus, as described in
>   "User-Drawn Controls," in this chapter.
>
> This is the only function your UserControl's GotFocus and LostFocus
>   events need to fulfill for a user-drawn control. You don't need to
>   raise GotFocus or LostFocus events for the user of your control,
>   because the container's extender provides these events if the
>   CanGetFocus property is True.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241743(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Thanks Richard. I'm working with VB6 and there are no propertys .Enabled and .CanGetFocus in my UserControl